# Only noise with alsa and pulseaudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I've tried for multiple days to set up my headphones. Whenever I play something via `aplay` or `speaker-test`, I only hear very loud white noise. I know it's not a hardware problem, because it worked with MS Windows.

Here is my `aplay -L` output:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CA0132 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=4
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=5
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=6
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 6
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
```

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:
`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

`amixer info`:

```
Card default 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xed920000 irq 164'
  Mixer name    : 'Creative CA0132'
  Components    : 'HDA:11020011,1458a046,00100918'
  Controls      : 45
  Simple ctrls  : 25
```

`amixer contents`:

```
numid=29,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=30,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=27,iface=CARD,name='Mic Phantom Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=28,iface=CARD,name='SPDIF Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=31,iface=CARD,name='SPDIF Phantom Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=99,step=0
  : values=99,99
  | dBscale-min=-90.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=45,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0
  : values=255,255
  | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Mic SVM Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Mic1-Boost (30dB) Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=99,step=0
  : values=99,99
  | dBscale-min=-90.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=36,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=32,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=33,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=34,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
  ; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=35,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=38,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Capture Default'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=37,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='AMic1/DMic Auto Detect Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='AMic1/DMic Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Analog-Mic2 Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Analog-Mic2 Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=99,step=0
  : values=90,90
  | dBscale-min=-90.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='CrystalVoice Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Crystalizer Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Dialog Plus Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Echo Cancellation Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Equalizer Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='HP/Speaker Auto Detect Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='HP/Speaker Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Noise Reduction Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='PlayEnhancement Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Smart Volume Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Voice Focus Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='VoiceFX Capture Switch'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=14
  ; Item #0 'Neutral'
  ; Item #1 'Female2Male'
  ; Item #2 'Male2Female'
  ; Item #3 'ScrappyKid'
  ; Item #4 'Elderly'
  ; Item #5 'Orc'
  ; Item #6 'Elf'
  ; Item #7 'Dwarf'
  ; Item #8 'AlienBrute'
  ; Item #9 'Robot'
  ; Item #10 'Marine'
  ; Item #11 'Emo'
  ; Item #12 'DeepVoice'
  ; Item #13 'Munchkin'
  : values=0
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='What U Hear Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='What U Hear Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=99,step=0
  : values=90,90
  | dBscale-min=-90.00dB,step=1.00dB,mute=0
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='X-Bass Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=40,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
numid=39,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
numid=44,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
numid=43,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
numid=41,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
numid=42,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=4
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
```

`ls -la /dev/snd`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      440 Jul 17 23:01 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root     4160 Jul 17 23:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       80 Jul 17 23:01 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 18 Jul 17 23:01 controlC0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 10 Jul 17 23:01 controlC1
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 17 Jul 17 23:01 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  9 Jul 17 23:01 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 12 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 11 Jul 17 23:34 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 16 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC0D1c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 15 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 13 Jul 17 23:01 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 14 Jul 17 23:01 pcmC0D4c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  6 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D10p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  7 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D11p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  8 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D12p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  2 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  3 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  4 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  5 Jul 17 23:11 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  1 Jul 17 23:01 seq
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 33 Jul 17 23:01 timer
```

`pactl info`:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 34
Server Protocol Version: 34
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 5
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: REDACTED
Host Name: REDACTED
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 14.2
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
Cookie: cf41:a508
```

My alsamixer:
[image: Alsamixer]

`/proc/asound/card0/codec#0`:

```
Codec: Creative CA0132
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x11020011
Subsystem Id: 0x1458a046
Revision Id: 0x100918
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 D3cold S3D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=1
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x49d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Device: name="CA0132 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x63 0x63]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x49d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x5a 0x5a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x49d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x5a 0x5a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x691: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="CA0132 Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x491: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x07 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10059b: Stereo Amp-In
  Device: name="CA0132 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0xe3 0xe3]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x1e4]: 16000 44100 48000 88200 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10059b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Analog-Mic2 Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Analog-Mic2 Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CA0132 Analog Mic-In2", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0xda 0xda]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x1e4]: 16000 44100 48000 88200 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x11
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100791: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Capture Default", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="CA0132 Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x1f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x0a [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10079b: Stereo Digital Amp-In
  Control: name="What U Hear Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="What U Hear Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CA0132 What U Hear", type="Audio", device=4
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0xda 0xda]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x1ec]: 16000 22050 44100 48000 88200 96000
    bits [0x1b]: 8 16 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x13
Node 0x0b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00010010: OUT EAPD
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014010: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x0c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400701: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x014580f0: [Jack] SPDIF Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = Optical, Color = Purple
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x05
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x014570f0: [Jack] SPDIF Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = Optical, Color = Yellow
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x0e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400681: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x01c530f0: [Jack] SPDIF In at Ext Rear
    Conn = Optical, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x0f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x0221401f: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x10 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x02216011: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Orange
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x1
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x11 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003734: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x02012014: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Grey
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x4
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic1-Boost (30dB) Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x37a791f0: [Jack] Mic at Oth Mobile-In
    Conn = Analog, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400681: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x908700f0: [Fixed] Line In at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x14 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70040c: Mono Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x1c]
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x15 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00600: Mono Digital
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x16 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00680: Mono Digital
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x17 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x49d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x5a, nsteps=0x63, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x5a 0x5a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5ec]: 16000 22050 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0x1f]: 8 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x500000f0: [N/A] Line Out at Int N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x17
```

I've tried connecting the headphones to the front and back headphone jack, but both just produce loud noise when playing a sound. When it goes back to idle, the noise stops.

Comment: What is it that you play?

Comment: @mmmm Just some random [wav](https://www.kozco.com/tech/piano2.wav) I found on the internet. Pressing backspace in my terminal with an empty line also just produces noise instead of the "bing"-sound.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

You have standard Intel HDA sound controller. Connected to this is a Creative CA0132 codec chip (codec = coder/decoder). This chip looks a bit unusual, and ALSA already picks up quite a few features you don't see on other codecs.

Googling for this chip finds e.g. [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/SoundBlasterOfficial/comments/i84832/creative_sound_core_3d_ca0132_r3dr3dizzxrzxriae5/), so it appears the codec driver in the kernel is still under quite a bit of development.

So the first step is to get the newest kernel installed that your distro allows. Maybe that already fixes the problem.

If it doesn't, have a look if there's a newer kernel source available [here](https://www.kernel.org), and learn how to compile and install a kernel on your distro from source. (It's not that hard, there are plenty of tutorials for each distro available). [Here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0132.c?h=v5.14-rc1) is the list of logs for changes to the CA0132 codec driver.

If this still doesn't help, then it's time to get into debugging what goes on into inside the codec, if you are up to it.

A HDA codec is organized as a graph, with nodes that corresponds to DACs, mixers etc., and loud white noise means that on the path your sound takes through the codec something that doesn't produce any real sound gets amplified too much, either drowing out the real signal, or because the real signal doesn't go where it should go.

The first step here is to play with the mixer settings in ALSA. If necessary, get Pulseaudio out of the picture by disabling it (as Pulseaudio takes over ALSA mixer settings in unpredictable ways). Play sound directly using `aplay`. Based on the information in your question you probably did that already, or you don't have Pulseaudio installed.

All the capture mixers seem to be muted, but turn down the volumes in all capture and special function mixers as well, just in case it is loopbacked through some node we don't see in ALSA.

Then figure out which playback mixers affect the volume of the white noise, and which don't.

If you are lucky, and if the real signal was drowned out, maybe you already hear something. If not, we need to start looking at the codec configuration (`/proc/asound/card0/codec#0` or similar), and then your driver probably also needs a quirk, so it's time to file a bug on the kernel bug tracker for that driver.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer!
I have upgraded my kernel to 5.13.2 (`uname -r`), but the problem is still there.
I have updated my question to provide more information.